# task kill command does not work for c# app

Tags: c#, process, user-input, messagebox, taskkill

I have c# winform bug: when the application is waiting for user input yes/no/cancel taskkill command line does not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `/F` to force shutdown if an application shows a modal dialog:

```
taskkill /F /IM <process name>

taskkill /F /PID <process id>
```

With `taskkill /?` you will get a list of all supported options.

Comment: I want somthing which not change the command line, I want to change something in c# code (in the application)